# Add a configuration option to remove the accept rate from the user box

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-exchange, accept-rate, user-card

[image]

There should be a config option to disable this feature on a site per site basis, just like there is an option to enable LaTeX.

Websites where it's useful to have it disabled:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

We do disable this on all *per-site metas*.

However, it's intentionally displayed and will remain in place on all *main* sites. This site, while technically a meta, is still considered a main site for historical reasons.

(We are also considering replacing "accept rate" with a broader "citizenship rate")

Comment: Are you envisioning a "citizenship rate" that incorporates a number of factors in addition to the accept rate?

Comment: indeed we are doing so

Answer (score 2):

Agree. Meanwhile, you can try hiding it with CSS for

```
div.accept-rate { display: none; }
```

Comment: @Arjan: **display: none** does the same thing as **visibility: hidden**, except the space used up by the element is reclaimed.

Comment: @Simon, true, but [the original post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/64286/revisions) just showed `div.accept-rate { }`. Thanks for explaining anyhow! I've removed my first comment, it might make more people wonder why it was upvoted. :-)

Comment: @Kop, thanks for filling the gap. I should've offered a more complete answer :P